# Function in JavaScript that can be called only once

Tags: javascript, function, design-patterns

I need to create a function which can be executed only once, in each time after the first it won't be executed. I know from C++ and Java about static variables that can do the work but I would like to know if there is a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: ~8 years later I created a feature request to my decorators lib (https://github.com/vlio20/utils-decorators) to have a decorator which will do exactly that (https://github.com/vlio20/utils-decorators/issues/77)

Answer (score 315, accepted):

If by "won't be executed" you mean "will do nothing when called more than once", you can create a closure:

```
var something = (function() {
    var executed = false;
    return function() {
        if (!executed) {
            executed = true;
            // do something
        }
    };
})();

something(); // "do something" happens
something(); // nothing happens
```

In answer to a comment by @Vladloffe (now deleted): With a global variable, other code could reset the value of the "executed" flag (whatever name you pick for it). With a closure, other code has no way to do that, either accidentally or deliberately.

As other answers here point out, several libraries (such as [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) and [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/)) have a little utility function (typically named `once()`<sup>[*]</sup>) that accepts a function as an argument and returns another function that calls the supplied function exactly once, regardless of how many times the returned function is called. The returned function also caches the value first returned by the supplied function and returns that on subsequent calls.

However, if you aren't using such a third-party library, but still want a utility function (rather than the nonce solution I offered above), it's easy enough to implement. The nicest version I've seen is [this one posted by David Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-once):

```
function once(fn, context) { 
    var result;
    return function() { 
        if (fn) {
            result = fn.apply(context || this, arguments);
            fn = null;
        }
        return result;
    };
}
```

I would be inclined to change `fn = null;` to `fn = context = null;`. There's no reason for the closure to maintain a reference to `context` once `fn` has been called.

Usage:

```
function something() { /* do something */ }
var one_something = once(something);

one_something(); // "do something" happens
one_something(); // nothing happens
```

---

<sup>[*]</sup> <sub>Be aware, though, that other libraries, such as [this Drupal extension to jQuery](https://www.drupal.org/node/444344), may have a function named `once()` that does something quite different.</sub>

Comment: works very good , can you explain the login behind it , how does     var executed = false;
 works

Comment: @EgyCode - This is explained nicely in the [MDN documentation on closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Comment: sorry , I meant logic , I never understood boolean var and how it works in that case executed

Comment: @EgyCode - In certain contexts (like in an `if` statement test expression), JavaScript expects one of the values `true` or `false` and the program flow reacts according to the value found when the expression is evaluated. Conditional operators like `==` always evaluate to a boolean value. A variable can also hold either `true` or `false`. (For more info, see the documentation on [boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Boolean), [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), and [falsey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).)

Comment: I don't understand why executed is not reset with every new call. Can someone explain it, please?

Comment: @JuanseCora - The outer function (where `executed` is initialized) is only executed once--when `something` is initialized. Note the `()` at the end of the statement that initialized `something`. That causes the outer function to be called and `something` is initialized with the *inner* function that is returned. Thus, each time `something` is called, only the inner function runs.

Comment: This code seems to assume that you have somewhere that you can run the code that initializes the `something` method and have it only run once.  If you put all that code in a call interceptor, then it will re-set and run first call to `something` each time it is all called.

Comment: @Vaccano - I'm not sure I understand your point. Are you talking about passing the initializer expression for I used for `something` directly into `window.setInterval()` or the like? That should work. The expression evaluates to a closure that is not reset each time. If you have something else in mind, please elaborate.

Comment: @TedHopp - Sorry for the confusion. I asked a separate question here that explains it better:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69651360/run-javascript-code-only-once-and-with-only-one-spot-to-put-the-code  I was able to deal with it by using local storage.

Comment: @Vaccano - Okay. Now I understand what you were asking, and I'm glad you found a solution. The local storage solution is a form of global variable (although at first glance it may not seem like it). Many other answers here use something like that. I see no reason to combine a global variable approach with a closure (as the answer to your question by Reflective suggests.)

Comment: here is a func that can be called only twice:

`
let bucketWith2Apples = (function () {
  let counter = 0;
  return function () {
    ++counter;
    if (counter <= 2) {
      console.log("here is an apple");
      // logic here that can be called only twice
      return;
    } else {
      console.log("no more apples left");
    }
  };
})();

bucketWith2Apples(); // here is an apple
bucketWith2Apples(); // here is an apple
bucketWith2Apples(); // no more apples left
bucketWith2Apples(); // no more apples left
bucketWith2Apples(); // no more apples left
`

Answer (score 72):

Replace it with a reusable NOOP *(no operation)* function.

```
// this function does nothing
function noop() {};

function foo() {
    foo = noop; // swap the functions

    // do your thing
}

function bar() {
    bar = noop; // swap the functions

    // do your thing
}
```

Comment: Why the down vote? What's the problem? This prevents the need to create a new flag for every function.

Comment: There are more elegant ways of achieving the intended functionality; check asawyer or hakra responses

Comment: @fableal: How is this inelegant? Again, it is very clean, requires less code, and doesn't require a new variable for every function that should be disabled. A *"noop"* is designed exactly for this sort of situation.

Comment: @fableal: I just looked at hakra's answer. So make a new closure and variable every time you need to do this to a new function? You have a very funny definition of "elegant".

Comment: Accordingly to asawyer's response, you only needed to do _.once(foo) or _.once(bar), and the functions themselves don't need to be aware of  being ran only once (no need for the noop and no need for the * = noop).

Comment: Goodness. That's useful if you want to have two version of the function. If not, `foo=noop;` is hardly a big deal or inelegant. The main point of that code is that the initial return is memoized. That can be useful if that's what is desired. That's not always the case.

Comment: You're right, that was my idea. My "inelegant" comes only from the global `noop()` and one having to write that `foo=noop` in every function intended to run only once. Only my opinion.

Comment: Would it be wrong to replace bar = noop with bar = function(){}, or bar = null?

Comment: @user1566694 - `bar = function(){};` would create a new function each time it was executed. That's why a global `noop()` function is preferable. Using `bar = null;` would cause an error the next time a function call was attempted, which is far from the desired "does nothing" behavior.

Comment: @TedHopp Can you explain "`bar = function(){};` would create a new function each time it was executed"? Surely by replacing bar with `function(){}` the code that creates the function will never be called again and the noop function will be called instead? Just point me in the right direction if my JS fundamentals in this regard are lacking...

Comment: @JonoCoetzee - Yes, you are correct that the code could not be executed more than once for any particular function (e.g., `bar`). However, if several functions needed this treatment, each would be creating its own replacement no-op function.

Comment: I would always keep `bar = noop;` at the top of the function, so that it is clearly visible, that if the function name changes, `bar = noop;` must be changed as well. If you keep it at the end of the function and have a big code block in between, you might forget to also rename this line of code, which would make the function callable multiple times again (not only once). This kind of misbehaviour can be extremely difficult to find.

Comment: Not really the best solution. If you're passing this function as a callback, it can still be called multiple times. For example: `setInterval(foo, 1000)` - and already this doesn't work anymore. You're just overwriting the reference in the current scope.

Comment: Reusable `invalidate` function which works with `setInterval` etc,.: https://jsbin.com/vicipar/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Trying to assign to a function reference will only work if the function is in the same file, not if it was imported from another file, you would only be changing your local reference to `bar` in this case

Answer (score 51):

### Point to an *empty* function once it has been called:

```js
function myFunc(){
     myFunc = function(){}; // kill it as soon as it was called
     console.log('call once and never again!'); // your stuff here
};
```

```html
<button onClick=myFunc()>Call myFunc()</button>
```

---

### Or, like so:

```js
var myFunc = function func(){
     if( myFunc.fired ) return;
     myFunc.fired = true;
     console.log('called once and never again!'); // your stuff here
};

// even if referenced & "renamed"
((refToMyfunc)=>{
  setInterval(refToMyfunc, 1000);
})(myFunc)
```

Comment: This solution is much more in the spirit of a highly dynamic language like Javascript. Why set semaphores, when you can simply empty the function once it has been used?

Comment: Very nice solution! This solution is also performing better than the closure approach. The only minor "drawback" is that you need to keep the function name in sync if the name changes.

Comment: The problem with this is that if there's another reference to the function somewhere (e.g. it was passed as an argument and stashed in another variable somewhere -- as in a call to `setInterval()`) then the reference will repeat the original functionality when called.

Comment: @TedHopp - [here's](http://jsbin.com/zujosinupe/edit?js,console,output) a special treatment for those cases

Comment: Yes, that's exactly like [Bunyk's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35984663/535871) on this thread. It's also similar to a closure (as in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12713611/535871)) but using a property instead of a closure variable. Both cases are quite different from your approach in this answer.

Answer (score 26):

UnderscoreJs has a function that does that, [underscorejs.org/#once](http://underscorejs.org/#once)

```
  // Returns a function that will be executed at most one time, no matter how
  // often you call it. Useful for lazy initialization.
  _.once = function(func) {
    var ran = false, memo;
    return function() {
      if (ran) return memo;
      ran = true;
      memo = func.apply(this, arguments);
      func = null;
      return memo;
    };
  };
```

Comment: It seems funny to me to have `once` accept arguments. You could do `squareo = _.once(square); console.log(squareo(1)); console.log(squareo(2));` and get `1` for both calls to `squareo`. Am I understanding this right?

Comment: @aschmied You are correct - the result of the first call's set of arguments will be memomized and returned for all other calls regardless of the parameter as the underlying function is never called again. In cases like that I do not suggest using the `_.once` method. See https://jsfiddle.net/631tgc5f/1/

Comment: @aschmied Or I guess use a separate call to once per argument set. I don't think this is really intended for that sort of use.

Comment: Handy if you're already using `_`; I wouldn't recommended depending upon the entire library for such a small bit of code.

Answer (score 14):

Talking about static variables, this is a little bit like closure variant:

```
var once = function() {
    if(once.done) return;

    console.log('Doing this once!');

    once.done = true;
};

once(); // Logs "Doing this once!"
once(); // Logs nothing
```

You could then reset a function if you wish:

```
once.done = false;
once(); // Logs "Doing this once!" again
```

Answer (score 6):

You could simply have the function "remove itself"

```
​function Once(){
    console.log("run");

    Once = undefined;
}

Once();  // run
Once();  // Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

But this may not be the best answer if you don't want to be swallowing errors.

You could also do this:

```
function Once(){
    console.log("run");

    Once = function(){};
}

Once(); // run
Once(); // nothing happens
```

*I need it to work like smart pointer, if there no elements from type A it can be executed, if there is one or more A elements the function can't be executed.*

```
function Conditional(){
    if (!<no elements from type A>) return;

    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I need it to work like smart pointer, if there no elements from type A it can be executed, if there is one or more A elements the function can't be executed.

Comment: @VladIoffe That's not what you asked.

Comment: This won't work if `Once` is passed as a call-back (e.g., `setInterval(Once, 100)`). The original function will continue to be called.

Answer (score 5):

```
var quit = false;

function something() {
    if(quit) {
       return;
    } 
    quit = true;
    ... other code....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

simple decorator that easy to write when you need

```
function one(func) {
  return function () {
     func && func.apply(this, arguments);
     func = null;
  }
}
```

using:

```
var initializer= one( _ =>{
      console.log('initializing')
  })

initializer() // 'initializing'
initializer() // nop
initializer() // nop
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using typescript with node and it was @I Hate Lazy's answer that inspired me. I just assigned my function to a **noop** function.

```
let printName = (name: string) => {
    console.log(name)
    printName = () => {}
}

printName('Sophia') // Sophia
printName('Nico')   // Nothing Happens
```

https://jsbin.com/yuzicek/edit?js,console

Comment: smart solution 

Comment: very nice ... i love it

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var fun = (function() {
  var called = false;
  return function() {
    if (!called) {
      console.log("I  called");
      called = true;
    }
  }
})()
```

Answer (score 2):

From some dude named Crockford... :)

```
function once(func) {
    return function () {
        var f = func;
        func = null;
        return f.apply(
            this,
            arguments
        );
    };
}
```

Comment: This is great if you think that `TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of null` is great. That's what you get the second time you invoke the returned function.

Answer (score 2):

Reusable `invalidate` function which works with `setInterval`:

```
var myFunc = function (){
  if (invalidate(arguments)) return;
  console.log('called once and never again!'); // your stuff here
};

const invalidate = function(a) {
  var fired = a.callee.fired;
  a.callee.fired = true;
  return fired;
}

setInterval(myFunc, 1000);
```

Try it on JSBin: https://jsbin.com/vicipar/edit?js,console

Variation of [answer from Bunyk](//stackoverflow.com/a/35984663/4592648)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6yL6t/

And the code:

```
function hashCode(str) {
    var hash = 0, i, chr, len;
    if (str.length == 0) return hash;
    for (i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
        chr   = str.charCodeAt(i);
        hash  = ((hash << 5) - hash) + chr;
        hash |= 0; // Convert to 32bit integer
    }
    return hash;
}

var onceHashes = {};

function once(func) {
    var unique = hashCode(func.toString().match(/function[^{]+\{([\s\S]*)\}$/)[1]);

    if (!onceHashes[unique]) {
        onceHashes[unique] = true;
        func();
    }
}
```

You could do:

```
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    once(function() {
        alert(i);
    });
}
```

And it will run only once :)

Answer (score 1):

Initial setup:

```
var once = function( once_fn ) {
    var ret, is_called;
    // return new function which is our control function 
    // to make sure once_fn is only called once:
    return function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
        if ( is_called ) return ret;
        is_called = true;
        // return the result from once_fn and store to so we can return it multiply times:
        // you might wanna look at Function.prototype.apply:
        ret = once_fn(arg1, arg2, arg3);
        return ret;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your using Node.js or writing JavaScript with browserify, consider the ["once" npm module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/once):

```
var once = require('once')

function load (file, cb) {
  cb = once(cb)
  loader.load('file')
  loader.once('load', cb)
  loader.once('error', cb)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to reuse the function in the future then this works well based on ed Hopp's code above (I realize that the original question didn't call for this extra feature!):

```
   var something = (function() {
   var executed = false;              
    return function(value) {
        // if an argument is not present then
        if(arguments.length == 0) {               
            if (!executed) {
            executed = true;
            //Do stuff here only once unless reset
            console.log("Hello World!");
            }
            else return;

        } else {
            // otherwise allow the function to fire again
            executed = value;
            return;
        }       
    }
})();

something();//Hello World!
something();
something();
console.log("Reset"); //Reset
something(false);
something();//Hello World!
something();
something();
```

The output look like:

```
Hello World!
Reset
Hello World!
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple example for turning on light only once.

```
function turnOnLightOnce() {
  let lightOn = false;

  return function () {
    if (!lightOn) {
      console.log("Light is not on...Turning it on for first and last time");
      lightOn = true;
    }

  };
}

const lightOn = turnOnLightOnce();
lightOn()  // Light is not on...Turning it on for first and last time
lightOn()
lightOn()
lightOn()
lightOn()
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-forked-ojo0i?file=/index.js

This happens due to closure in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

```
function once (fn1) {
  var ran = false
  var memo = null
  var fn = function(...args) {
    if(ran) {return memo}
    ran = true
    memo = fn1.apply(null, args)
    return memo
  }
  return fn
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### FOR EVENT HANDLER

If the function is a callback for an event listener, there is already a built-in option in the `addEventListner` method for just executing the `callback` once.

It can accept 3 parameters

- Type
- callback
- options

`options` is an object that has a property called `once`

ex:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');

const callbackFunc = () => {
  alert('run')
}

button.addEventListener('click', callbackFunc, { once: true })
```

```html
<button id="button">Click Once</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use underscore "once" function:

```
var initialize = _.once(createApplication);
initialize();
initialize();
// Application is only created once.
```

http://underscorejs.org/#once

Comment: nah, it's too ugly when you start calling it with arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
var init = function() {
    console.log("logges only once");
    init = false;
}; 

if(init) { init(); }

/* next time executing init() will cause error because now init is 
   -equal to false, thus typing init will return false; */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!window.doesThisOnce){
  function myFunction() {
    // do something
    window.doesThisOnce = true;
  };
};
```

Comment: It's a bad practice to pollute the global scope (a.k.a window)

Comment: I agree with you but someone might get something out of it.

Comment: This doesn't work. When that code is first executed, the function is created. Then when the function is called it is executed and the global is set to false, but the function can still be called a next time.

Comment: It is not set to false anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ramda, you can use the function ["once"](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#once).

A quote from the documentation:

> once Function 
>   (a… → b) → (a… → b)
>   PARAMETERS
>   Added in v0.1.0
>
> Accepts a function fn and returns a function that guards invocation of fn such that fn can only ever be called once, no matter how many times the returned function is invoked. The first value calculated is returned in subsequent invocations.

```
var addOneOnce = R.once(x => x + 1);
addOneOnce(10); //=> 11
addOneOnce(addOneOnce(50)); //=> 11
```

Answer (score 0):

keep it as simple as possible

```
function sree(){
  console.log('hey');
  window.sree = _=>{};
}
```

You can see the result

[image: script result]

Comment: If you are inside module, just use `this` instead of `window`

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery allows to call the function only once using the method [one()](https://api.jquery.com/one/):**

```js
let func = function() {
  console.log('Calling just once!');
}
  
let elem = $('#example');
  
elem.one('click', func);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Function that can be called only once</p>
  <button id="example" >JQuery one()</button>
</div>
```

**Implementation using JQuery method [on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/):**

```js
let func = function(e) {
  console.log('Calling just once!');
  $(e.target).off(e.type, func)
}
  
let elem = $('#example');
  
elem.on('click', func);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Function that can be called only once</p>
  <button id="example" >JQuery on()</button>
</div>
```

**Implementation using native JS:**

```js
let func = function(e) {
  console.log('Calling just once!');
  e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, func);
}
  
let elem = document.getElementById('example');
  
elem.addEventListener('click', func);
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Functions that can be called only once</p>
  <button id="example" >ECMAScript addEventListener</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tossing my hat in the ring for fun, added advantage of memoizing

```js
const callOnce = (fn, i=0, memo) => () => i++ ? memo : (memo = fn());
```

```js
// usage
const myExpensiveFunction = () => { return console.log('joe'),5; }
const memoed = callOnce(myExpensiveFunction);
memoed(); //logs "joe", returns 5
memoed(); // returns 5
memoed(); // returns 5
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IIFE. IIFE means Immediately Invoked Function Expression and the result is to call a function only once by the time is created.
Your code will be like this:

```
(function () {
  //The code you want to execute only one time etc...
  console.log("Hello world");
})()
```

Additionally, this way the data in the function remains encapsulated.
Of course and you can return values from the function and stored them into a new variable, by doing:

```
const/let value = (function () {
  //The code you want to execute only one time etc...
  const x = 10;
  return x;
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function x()
{
  let a=0;
  return function check()
   {
    if(!a++) 
     {
       console.log("This Function will execute Once.")
       return;
      }
     console.log("You Can't Execute it For the Second Time.")
     return;
    }
  }

 z=x()
 z() //Op - This Function will execute once
 z() //OP - You can't Execute it for the second time.
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it useful to just have a simple function that just returns true once, so you can keep the side effects higher up.

```
let once = () => !! (once = () => false);

once() // true
once() // false
```

Use like this:

```
if (once()) {
  sideEffect()
}
```

This exploits the fact that you can coerce an assignment expression to return `true` while changing the same function into a function that returns `false`.

If you must have it execute a function, it can be adapted using a ternary:

```
let once = (x) => !! (once = () => false) ? x() : false;
```

Now it accepts a single function as an argument. Fun fact, the second `false` is never reached.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function once(func, context){
      let ran;
    
      return function (){
        if(func){
          ran= func.apply(context || this.arguments);
          func=null;
        }
        return ran;
      }
    }
    
    const hello = once(()=>console.log("Hello"))
    
    hello(); //output - Hello
    hello(); //null
    hello(); //null
```

Using a closure return function and if the function calls again then returns null

Answer (score -1):

```
// This is how function in JavaScript can be called only once    

let started = false;     
      if (!started) {
                    start() { // "do something" }
                }
                started = true;
            }
```

Comment: This is how function in JavaScript that can be called only once

Comment: You don't even have a function here.

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score -2):

This one is useful for preventing infinite loops (using jQuery):

```
<script>
var doIt = true;
if(doIt){
  // do stuff
  $('body').html(String($('body').html()).replace("var doIt = true;", 
                                                  "var doIt = false;"));
} 
</script>
```

If you're worried about namespace pollution, subsitute a long, random string for "doIt".

Answer (score -2):

It helps to prevent sticky execution

```
var done = false;

function doItOnce(func){
  if(!done){
    done = true;
    func()
  }
  setTimeout(function(){
    done = false;
  },1000)
}
```

Comment: the loop  runs 206 time 
I Meuser my CPU speed thanks loool