# execute function just once

Tags: javascript, onclick

I read this thread and tried to use Ted Hopps method
[Function in javascript that can be called only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713564/function-in-javascript-that-can-be-called-only-once)

But seems that i can't make it work properly. I want to create a div with JS by onclick="function()" on an image. But i want to do that just once.

```
 function runOnce(f){           

    var executed = false;
    return function () {
        if (!executed) {
            executed = true;
         return f.apply(this,arguments);
        }
    };
}
function rollover() { 
var new1=runOnce(myfunction);
new1(1);
} 

function myfunction(){


var tr1 = document.createElement("tr1");
tr1.style.width = "50%";
tr1.style.height = "100%";
tr1.style.background = "red";
tr1.style.color = "white";
tr1.style.right= "0px"
tr1.style.top= "0px"
tr1.style.padding= "2%"
tr1.style.opacity= "0.6"
tr1.style.position = "fixed";
tr1.innerHTML = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum";

document.body.appendChild(tr1);



}
```

I call the rollover function from onclick

```
<img class="trans01button" onclick="rollover(1)" src="images/backgroundfragments_03.jpg" alt="Translation games" >
```

My problem is that it still executes the function multiple times. 
I made a jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RE3fp/ here but i can't make it work while my dreamweaver version works. I mean i can't make the "myfunction" div even to appear, while my problem is that it executes everytime i click the image.

Comment: In `rollover` you're creating a new `runOnce` every time, when you should be using the result of the `runOnce(myfunction)` as the function invoked when you click.

Comment: Of course you can't because you have error in your code. Just look on console. Here you can find updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RE3fp/1/

Comment: What was wrong i can't see it. It says that the rollover is not defined but i don't see the difference from the two fiddles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need move this line: `var executed = false;` outside of `runOnce` function scope.

### [Workind DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RE3fp/2/)

Because **always** when you go inside `runOnce` function you set yout flag to **false**.

Comment: Good to hear that. Do you understand now what kind of issue you made?

Comment: I think so , i was initialising everytime the runOnce as false which means that it had to execute everytime called.