# how to emit a node function only one at a time from client side using node.js and socket.io

Tags: jquery, node.js

I had a function which emit a node in 15 min interval.Now if the node
 is fire from two browser the function is excited two times.while i want 
to get it execute only one at a time,no matter from how many client 
machine it get fried.I am using node.js and socket.io.is there is any way
 to do that.

**server.js**

```
socket.on('autobid',function(){

console.log('autobidcalltest');//get prints two time if fired from 2 browser

});
```

Comment: dirty: is a simple flag an option? Setting it to true when the function is executed the first time, and revert it when done? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713564/function-in-javascript-that-can-be-called-only-once

Comment: No the result is same,as the function is called at the same time