# How to run JS function only one time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scroll

I want to fire a popup when the user scrolls to a specific element id from my website.

At the moment I manages to do this, but it works in a loop and I can't stop the function after it was executed one time.

Follows my JS code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
 var executed = false;
  if (!executed){ 
  executed = true;
      var hT = $('#scroll-to').offset().top,
      hH = $('#scroll-to').outerHeight(),
      wH = $(window).height(),
      wS = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
   <!--
     window.setTimeout('window.location="javascript:showSuccessToast();"; ',2000);
     // -->
  }}
  });
```

I can't understand why the function executes, when "executed" variable becomes true.
How can i manage it to fire only one time *showsuccessToast* ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function in javascript that can be called only once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713564/function-in-javascript-that-can-be-called-only-once)

Comment: `$(window).one("scroll", function() { ... });` No need to handle this yourself.

Comment: @Frederic, but point to a piece of doc, so he can follow. http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: `window.setTimeout('window.location="javascript:showSuccessToast();"; ',2000);` ... what? Why not just `setTimeout(showSuccessToast, 2000)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The var executed is always set false when the scroll event happens. Which means it is useless in your function.

Put the executed out of the event function should work.

```
   var executed = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var hT = $('#scroll-to').offset().top,
  hH = $('#scroll-to').outerHeight(),
  wH = $(window).height(),
  wS = $(this).scrollTop();
 if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
if (!executed){ executed = true;
     <!--
     window.setTimeout('window.location="javascript:showSuccessToast();"; ',20);
     // -->
 }}
 });
```

Comment: What if the user will refresh the page? will it fire again?

Comment: now it fires only when i reload the page and the id is present in the window :( if i scroll from the top to the id, it doesn't fire

Comment: Of course it will fire(what do you mean fire?) again. The memory will be refreshed when the user refresh the page. So executed will be reset to false.

Comment: Who the hell changed my answer to a incorrect one??

Answer (score 2):

Your function executes from scratch every time the event is fired - this includes the initialization of `executed`. So in other words, every time your function runs, you're setting `executed` back to false!

To fix this, you need to pull the variable definition outside of the function:

```
var executed = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (!executed) { 
        executed = true;

        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: now it fires only when i reload the page and the id is present in the window :( if i scroll from the top to the id, it doesn't fire

Comment: @GeorgeL. You'll have to move the `executed = true` line to the place that you want to execute only once. Probably in this case inside the if block.

Comment: but it is in the if block

Comment: I mean the `if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){` block. If that doesn't work either, the problem is in the rule logic.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @JJJ - you probably want to move the line where you set `executed` to true to right after your success toast gets triggered.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use [unbind()](https://api.jquery.com/unbind/) as the following JS code shows:

```
$(window).scroll(myScrollFunction);
function myScrollFcuntion()
{
    // do things
    $(window).unbind("scroll", myScrollFunction);
}
```

Comment: well, now it doesn't fire the Event