# jQuery - stop/cancel scroll event callback after a certain scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the number to count up to its designated value and stay there, but because the function gets called every time the page is being scrolled below a certain height, then it goes back to 1.

The solution would be to make it call the function only once when the page has been scrolled to below the certain height.

Ive tried placing the `.one()` method several places but that didn't help

http://jsfiddle.net/d7vKd/1543/

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $("#mydiv").position().top) {
    window.randomize = function() {
      $('.radial-progress1').attr('data-progress', Math.floor(94));
    };
    $('.count').each(function() {
      $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
      }, {
        duration: 6000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function(now) {
          $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
      });
    });
    setTimeout(window.randomize, 200);
  }
})
```

Comment: Have you considered `$(document).off("scroll")` when your trigger is met?

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23685237/104380) regarding calling a function once

Comment: the $(document).off("scroll") conflicts because i have another on scroll function on my website(hide/show header navigation). do you know another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [unbind](http://jqapi.com/#p=off) your `scroll` event once the callback has met its demands:

```
$(document).on('scroll.someName', function(){
  var isPassedPos = $(this).scrollTop() >= $("#mydiv").position().top;

  if( isPassedPos ){
    $(document).off('scroll.someName') // <-------------- remove the event listener

    window.randomize = function() {
      $('.radial-progress1').attr('data-progress', Math.floor(94));
    };

    $('.count').each(function() {
      $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
      }, {
        duration: 6000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function(now) {
          $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
      });
    });

    setTimeout(window.randomize, 200);
  }
})
```

Comment: Oh no, that solution created another issue, can your solution be isolated somehow? because i have another $(document).scroll(function(){ on my website that gets broken now :)

Comment: $(document).scroll(function(){
     if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
         $("#topnav").removeClass("transp").addClass('wtbck');
     } else {
        $("#topnav").removeClass("wtbck").addClass('transp');
     } 
 });

Comment: @Vegapunk - sure. update the solution to use [events namespace](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) `someName` (choose your own), so the `off` method will only remove that specific event and not **all** the `scroll` event listeners.

Comment: i changed document to window, fixed it for me, hope it wont cause any issues on the different platforms :)

Comment: @Vegapunk - it won't, but you should really use namespaces nonetheless. Any particular reason you have not chosen this answer as the correct one?