# Execute js function once onClick

Tags: javascript, json, function

When a searchbox is submitted, I execute 2 API functions.

```
document.getElementById('getWeather').onclick = function(){
  // init data stream
  getAPIdata();
  getAPIWeerdata();
};
```

The first one `getAPIdata();` is for the searchbox itself and of course the value can change when the user submits again. So this can get executed more than once.

The second one on the other hand `getAPIWeerdata();` gets executed once when the user submits the searchbox.

Can I create something like `getAPIWeerdata();.ExecuteOnce`

Comment: check _lodash library once function

Comment: or check this answers over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713564/function-in-javascript-that-can-be-called-only-once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to use a boolean that is set to false when you call that onclick function, and call `getAPIWeerdata()` only if that bool is true. Make sure to call `getAPIWeerdata()` before you set your bool to false.

So :

```
var boolean = true;

document.getElementById('getWeather').onclick = function(){
// init data stream
getAPIdata(); 
if (boolean) {
getAPIWeerdata();
}
boolean = false;
};
```

Comment: Yes I realised  this as soon as I posted this question, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Set a `data-` attribute on the respective dom element:

```
document.getElementById('getWeather').onclick = function(){
    // init data stream
    getAPIdata();
    if (!document.getElementById('getWeather').hasAttribute('data-inited')) {
        getAPIWeerdata();
        document.getElementById('getWeather').setAttribute('data-inited', 1'); // Value does not matter
    }
}
```