# Can you disable links when there is no internet connection and enable them when internet connection returns?

Tags: javascript

When connection returns, all I get is NULL for the anchors.

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  setInterval(function(){  /*check ~every second*/
  var status = navigator.onLine?'Menu Enabled!':'Menu Disabled!';
```

the first part sets an attribute when the connection is lost

```
            var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        if(status == 'Menu Disabled!') {   /*if connection is lost*/            
            for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
            var href = anchors[i].href;
            anchors[i].setAttribute("rel", href);
            anchors[i].href = "javascript:;"              
                                                     }
                                        }
```

this part is supposed to remove the attribute and restore the anchor

```
       if(status == 'Menu Enabled!') {    /* if connection is reconnected */   
            for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
            var href = anchors[i].getAttribute("rel");
            anchors[i].removeAttribute("rel");
            anchors[i].href = href
                                                     }        
                                      }
 }, 1000);
 </script
```

Comment: Yes, you can accomplish your goal - but not with that code. How are you "notifying" the application that `status` has changed?

Comment: Isn't it polling the script every second with the interval? The first part works to disable the anchors, but I cant seem to return it to original state.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if Internet Connection Exists with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384167/check-if-internet-connection-exists-with-jquery)

Comment: @EPH - please see my answer.

Comment: @EPH - hello? Are you there?

Comment: Sorry I was trying to apply the code, I can't seem to get it to work. status doesn't seem to be defined

Comment: You do see it work in my answer snippet right? By work, I mean it literally Changs the attributes as you designed.

Comment: I see the two links and when I click on the links they don't resolve. Thats the state I need them in when there is no internet connection. I need them to change back to clickable when the internet connection returns. Thats why I was using navigator.

Comment: Yes, change `false` to `navigator.onLine` - I changed it to force the offline condition - it works the way you want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event handlers should be defined at the bottom of your JavaScript which should all be contained within the `head` element. If properly positioned this code will work in strict conditions. You can [read more at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine#Specification).

```
window.onclick = function(event)
{
 if (!navigator.onLine)
 {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert('Notice: you are no longer connected to the Internet, please check your connection and try again.');
 }
}
```

Comment: John, this is what I was looking for! How simple! I really wasted a lot of time on un-needed code. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I'm glad to have helped. Keep in mind a good GUI will let the user know *why* something isn't working, e.g. `alert('Notice: you are no longer connected to the Internet, please check your connection and try again.');` and you will help your visitors and they'll be happy to have minimized the time wasted from their cat gnawing on their cables.

Comment: I've updated it to include the `alert`. If you want lots of good examples of snippets of code visit the link in to my site (JAB) and visit Documentation ⇨ JavaScript. You can click on the linked headers to view the code of any given function and most functions are already documented.

Answer (score 2):

Wow. So many great answers between when I started writing and testing it vs when I finished!

Here's a way to disable *only* the links via a function that does nothing if accidentally executed a second time thanks to [a technique posted by Ted Hopp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12713611/7158380).

```js
const setItUp = (function() {
    let executed = false;
    return function() {
        if (!executed) {
            executed = true;
            
            const linkList = document.querySelectorAll('a');
            for (let link of linkList) {
                link.addEventListener(
                    "click",
                    function(event) {
                        if (!window.navigator.onLine) { //not a perfect check. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine for more.
                            alert('Sorry! Your browser seems to be off-line!');
                            event.preventDefault();
                    }    },
                    false
                );
    }    }    }
})();
setItUp();
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="https://cnn.com/">cnn.com</a><br>
        <a href="https://google.com/">google.com</a><br>
        <div>standard text that's not a link</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Beware that window.navigator.onLine is not universal.** See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine for details.

Comment: Super, I thinks this is better than window.onclick.

Answer (score 1):

You simply were missing a couple of `{ }` here and there. The code below is your code but edited.

Additionally, you could make your code much more efficient by changing a couple things here or there, but this answers your question.

Note is set the ternary to **false** to force the *offline* condition

```js
setInterval(
  function() {
    var status = false ? 'Menu Enabled!' : 'Menu Disabled!';
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    if (status == 'Menu Disabled!') { /*if connection is lost*/
      for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        var href = anchors[i].href;
        anchors[i].setAttribute("rel", href);
        anchors[i].href = "javascript:;"
      }
    }
    if (status == 'Menu Enabled!') { /* if connection is reconnected */
      for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        var href = anchors[i].getAttribute("rel");
        anchors[i].removeAttribute("rel");
        anchors[i].href = href
      }
    }
  }, 1000);
```

```html
<a href="google.com">Google</a>
<a href="yahoo.com">Google</a>
```