# Call function in java script once with closure

Tags: javascript

I want call function once in java script and for implement this idea I write this code and I use closure

```
function initialize() {
  let called = 0;
  return function() {
    if (called > 0) {
      return
    } else {
      called++;
      console.log('view has been set!')
    }

  }
}

const start1 = initialize();
start1();
start1();
start1();
```

I call start1 function third time and when I run this code I get once this output "view has been set!" in console.
But I notice I can call initialize function many times and create different start function for example

```
const start1 = initialize();
const start2 = initialize();
start1();
start2();
```

This time in output I have twice "view has been set!".
How can I fix that. thanks.

Comment: Is this just for learning or for solving an actual problem?

Comment: Just for learning I try used closure for different things.

Comment: written like this you will always get it one time. If you name the closure function and call it one time after the function declaration it will be called only one time.

Comment: Looks like it's already answered here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713564/function-in-javascript-that-can-be-called-only-once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By keeping the structure of calling `initialize`, you need a closure which works without the first call of `initialize`.

Then you need a nested function to get the inner function for the working part.

```js
const initialize = (() => {
  let called = 0;
  return () => () => {
    if (called <= 0) {
      called++;
      console.log('view has been set!');
    }
  };
})();


const start1 = initialize();
const start2 = initialize();
start1();
start2();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `initialize` function every times a new `called` variable is created which assigned to value `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is a singleton. You can try this approach.

```js
 
class initialize {
    constructor(){
        
     if(! initialize.instance){
       this._data = [];
      

       initialize.instance = this;
       console.log('view has been set!')
     }
  
     return initialize.instance;
    }
  
    dosmt=()=>{
        console.log("smt"    )
    }
 
  }
  
  const instance = new initialize();
  Object.freeze(instance);



  const start1 = new initialize() ;
  const start2 = new initialize();
  const start3 = new initialize();
start1.dosmt() 
start2.dosmt() 
start3.dosmt()
```