# React Native: How to prevent an onLayout function from being called on every re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, render

My React Native component has a prop `this.props.a` that gets updated every 60s elsewhere in the app. Within this component, I have a `<View>` with an `onLayout()` function. This `onLayout` gets called every 60s when the props are updated. Is there a way to get it to be called only the first time the component is rendered, and not on subsequent re-renders?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713564/function-in-javascript-that-can-be-called-only-once - looking for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! `<View onLayout={()=> onLayout()}/>` This part `()=>`will prevent the onLayout function form being called on render.

Hope this helps! /W

Comment: somehow this indeed helps. lol