# How to only let the user call my function one

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am trying to **move** a box by letting the user click a **button** but I only want the user to be able to call the function once in 'javascript'.

```
function myMove() {
  let id = null; let id2 = null;
  const elem = document.getElementById("animate");   
  let pos = 0;
  clearInterval(id);
  id = setInterval(frame, 1);


  function frame() {
    if (pos == 250) {
      clearInterval(id);
       id2 = setInterval(backframe, 1);
    } else {
      pos++; 
      elem.style.top = pos + "px"; 
      elem.style.left = pos + "px"; 
    }
  }
  function backframe() {
    if (pos == 0) {
      clearInterval(id2);
      id = setInterval(frame, 1);
    } else {
      pos--; 
      elem.style.top = pos + "px"; 
      elem.style.left = pos + "px"; 
    }
  }
   
}
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Comment: [javascript call function only once](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+call+function+only+once+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: See [*Function in JavaScript that can be called only once*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713564/function-in-javascript-that-can-be-called-only-once).

Comment: Offtopic, but you don't need both `id` and `id2`, since when `backframe` fires, `frame` is not running. You can safely use only `id` variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add an event listener, that just fires once, `addEventListener` can accept 3 arguments: *type, listener, and options*.

`options` is an object that has a property called `once`, you have set it to `true`.

Ex:

```
button.addEventListener('click', myMove, { once: true })
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply these modification to your code:

```
let wasUsed = false;

function myMove() {
  if (wasUsed) return; // stops the function if it has ran before
  wasUsed = true;
  // the rest of your function doesn't change:
  let id = null; let id2 = null;
  ...
}
```